# Spotfire Connection to Blob (Storage Accounts)

Tags: azure, blob, spotfire, azure-blob-storage

I am looking for the process of connecting Spotfire to Blob Storage Accounts.

If anyone can help me out by explaining the steps to connect Spotfire to Blob.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, I have the OData connector installed and is available for the connection but I am looking for steps to connect Blob through OData. I am trying this process, https://docs.tibco.com/pub/sfire-analyst/7.11.1/doc/html/en-US/TIB_sfire-analyst_UsersGuide/connectors/odata/odata_loading_data_from_microsoft_azure_marketplace.htm?_ga=2.105103427.170585520.1549874449-763608420.1527084145#finding_the_service_url_on_azure_marketplace but getting an error. I think am not using correct Service URL or the Acc Key. Wanted to know what should be the Service URL and the Acc key.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the Spotfire Connector for OData.

for more information on the product, see the TIBCO Spotfire Connectors [system requirements](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/spotfire/general/sr/GUID-71EDC198-D037-4A3B-B296-4B3EC2CAA0CC.html) and [documentation](https://docs.tibco.com/products/tibco-spotfire-connectors-7-6-1).

Comment: Hi Niko, Tnx for your response I have the OData connector installed and is available for the connection but I am looking for steps to connect Blob through OData. I am trying this process, https://docs.tibco.com/pub/sfire-analyst/7.11.1/doc/html/en-US/TIB_sfire-analyst_UsersGuide/connectors/odata/odata_loading_data_from_microsoft_azure_marketplace.htm?_ga=2.105103427.170585520.1549874449-763608420.1527084145#finding_the_service_url_on_azure_marketplace but getting an error. I think am not using correct Service URL or the Acc Key. Wanted to know what should be the Service URL and the Acc key.